# How can I use contradictory evidence?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

While writing [about how to do subtyping in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36680559/791604), it occurred to me that it would be very convenient to be able to "use" contradictory evidence such as `True ~ False` to inform the compiler about dead branches. With another standard empty type, `Void`, the `EmptyCase` extension allows you to mark a dead branch (i.e. one that contains a value of type `Void`) this way:

```
use :: Void -> a
use x = case x of
```

I'd like to do something similar for unsatisfiable `Constraint`s.

Is there a term which can be given the type `True ~ False => a` but cannot be given the type `a`?

Comment: I am no expert, but I guess that as soon as a constraint involves no variables, GHC tries to produce a dictionary/proof for it. If that fails, a type error is generated. It would be interesting to see what would happen if e.g. `'c' && True :: Bool ~ Char => Bool`, allowing the constraint to float around. Perhaps the fail-early method is more efficient or produces better errors (?)

Comment: You could `EmptyCase` on a [`Dict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.6/docs/Data-Constraint.html#g:2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can often do this by separating the exact nature of the evidence from the way you plan to use it. If the type checker *sees* that you've introduced an absurd constraint, it will bark at you. So the trick is to delay that equality behind `:~:`, and then to manipulate the equality evidence using generally reasonable functions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables, DataKinds,
      PolyKinds, RankNTypes #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

module TrueFalse where
import Data.Type.Equality

data Foo (a :: Bool) where
  Can :: Foo 'False
  Can't :: (forall x . x) -> Foo 'True

extr :: Foo 'True -> a
extr (Can't x) = x

subst :: a :~: b -> f a -> f b
subst Refl x = x

whoop :: 'False :~: 'True -> a
whoop pf = extr $ subst pf Can
```

The `whoop` function seems to be approximately what you're looking for.

---

As András Kovács commented, you could even just use `EmptyCase` on the `'False :~: 'True` value. At present (7.10.3), unfortunately, `EmptyCase` [doesn't warn about non-exhaustive matches](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10746). This will hopefully be fixed soon.

Update 2019: that bug has been fixed.

Comment: While trying to build an answer myself I also noticed that bug. It's a nasty one! There's some good reading at that link.

Answer (score 4):

Such a constraint will cause a type error if it ever appears as a given constraint. In general, this applies to any constraint the typechecker deems impossible.

Even writing a function

```
f :: ('True ~ 'False) => x
f = undefined
```

does not typecheck, because the context of a function is a given constraint in the body of the function - and `'True ~ 'False` simply cannot appear as a given constraint.

At best you could have e.g.

```
import Data.Type.Equality ((:~:)(..))

type family (==) (a :: k) (b :: k) :: Bool where 
  a == a = 'True 
  a == b = 'False 

f :: ((x == y) ~ 'False) => x :~: y -> a
-- f Refl = undefined -- Inaccessible code 
f = \case{}
```

which again comes back to an `EmptyCase`, this time on the `:~:`. Note that

```
f :: ((x == y) ~ 'False, x ~ y) => a
```

also reduces to a trivially impossible constraint, because `x == x` reduces to `True`. You could write an equality predicate which doesn't reduce for trivially equal types (e.g. the one in `Data.Type.Equality`), which allows you to write:

```
import Data.Type.Equality 

f :: ((x == y) ~ 'False, x ~ y) => Proxy '(x,y) -> a 
f = undefined
```

There may be a way to write this function without `undefined` but it is sort of moot anyways since this type is immediately reduced by GHC:

> ```
> >:t f
> f :: forall (k :: BOX) (y :: k) a. ((y == y) ~ 'False) => Proxy '(y, y) -> a
> ```

Even without the constraint there, it is definitionally impossible to call the function `Proxy '(y,y) -> a` with two different types. There is no way to hide an equality constraint `~` from the typechecker - you must use a different form of equality, one which does not reduce to `~`.