# How to use a refutation to direct the type checker in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, dependent-type, theorem-proving

Does filling the hole in the following program necessarily require non-constructive means? If yes, is it still the case if `x :~: y` decidable?

More generally, how do I use a refutation to guide the type checker?

(I am aware that I can work around the problem by defining `Choose` as a GADT, I'm asking specifically for type families)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module PropositionalDisequality where

import Data.Type.Equality
import Data.Void

type family Choose x y where
  Choose x x = 1
  Choose x _ = 2

lem :: (x :~: y -> Void) -> Choose x y :~: 2
lem refutation = _
```

Comment: I think you need reflection so that you can pattern match on `x` and `y`. I'm afraid I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to that, though.

Comment: I think you'll not be able to persuade GHC to take the second equation for `Choose`. I believe that is chosen only when `x` and `y` are instantiated to "definitely different types", e.g. different constructors.

Comment: I don’t know how to do this in Haskell or any other language. But I think in a made-up dependently typed language it would look something like `lem {x:Type} {y:Type} (refutation : x :~: y -> Void) : Choose x y :~: 2 = match Choose x y with | 1 -> (match refutation Refl with | _ -> .) | 2 -> Refl | _ -> .` That is you need to have `x` and `y` in scope and then by matching on `Choose x y` you can get a proof that `x :~: y` in the 1 branch and apply your refutation to it to construct `Void`. Then you can prove anything from that so you can prove your consequent. The 2 case is direct.

Comment: @DanRobertson am I correct in thinking that the `1` case uses the injectivity of the `Choose` and wouldn't work if it wasn't?

Comment: You might also like [How can I use contradictory evidence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36680830/791604).

Comment: @DanRobertson, I very much doubt that `Choose` can be implemented at all in a real dependently typed language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try hard enough to implement a function, you can convince yourself
that it is not possible. If you're not convinced, the argument can be made
more formal: we enumerate programs exhaustively to find that none is possible. It turns out there's only half a dozen of meaningful cases to consider.

I wonder why this argument is not made more often.

Totally not accurate summary:

- Act I: proof search is easy.
- Act II: dependent types too.
- Act III: Haskell is still fine for writing dependently typed programs.

## I. The proof search game

First we define the search space.

We can reduce any Haskell definition to one of the form

```
lem = (exp)
```

for some expression `(exp)`. Now we only need to find a single expression.

Look at all possible ways of making an expression in Haskell:
https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-220003
(this doesn't account for extensions, exercise for the reader).

It fits a page in a single column, so it's not *that* big to start with.
Moreover, most of them are sugar for some form of function application or
pattern-matching; we can also desugar away type classes with dictionary
passing, so we're left with a ridiculously small lambda calculus:

- lambdas, `\x -> ...`
- pattern-matching, `case ... of ...`
- function application, `f x`
- constructors, `C` (including integer literals)
- constants, `c` (for primitives that cannot be written in terms of the constructs above, so various built-ins (`seq`) and maybe FFI if that counts)
- variables (bound by lambdas and cases)

We can exclude every constant on the grounds that I think the question is
really about pure lambda calculus (or the reader can enumerate the constants,
to exclude black-magic constants like `undefined`, `unsafeCoerce`,
`unsafePerformIO` that make everything collapse (any type is inhabited and, for
some of those, the type system is unsound), and to be left with white-magic
constants to which the present theoretical argument can be generalized via a
well-funded thesis).

We can also reasonably assume that we want a solution with no recursion involved
(to get rid of noise like `lem = lem`, and `fix` if you felt like you couldn't
part with it before), and which actually has a normal form, or preferably, a
canonical form with respect to βη-equivalence. In other words, we refine and
examine the set of possible solutions as follows.

- `lem :: _ -> _` has a function type, so we can assume [WLOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) that its definition starts with a lambda:

  ```
  -- Any solution
  lem = (exp)

  -- is η-equivalent to a lambda
  lem = \refutation -> (exp) refutation

  -- so let's assume we do have a lambda
  lem = \refutation -> _hole
  ```

Now enumerate what could be under the lambda.

- It could be a constructor,
  which then has to be `Refl`, but there is no proof that `Choose x y ~ 2` in
  the context (here we could formalize and enumerate the type equalities the
  typechecker knows about and can derive, or make the syntax of coercions
  (proofs of equalities) explicit and keep playing this proof search game
  with them), so this doesn't type check:

  ```
  lem = \refutation -> Refl
  ```

  Maybe there is some way of constructing that equality proof, but then the
  expression would start with something else, which is going to be another
  case of the proof.
- It could be some application of a constructor `C x1 x2 ...`, or the
  variable `refutation` (applied or not); but there's no possible way that's
  well-typed, it has to somehow produce a `(:~:)`, and `Refl` is really the
  only way.
- Or it could be a `case`. WLOG, there is no nested `case` on the left, nor any
  constructor, because the expression could be simplified in both cases:

  ```
  -- Any left-nested case expression
  case (case (e) of { C x1 x2 -> (f) }) { D y1 y2 -> (g) }

  -- is equivalent to a right-nested case
  case (e) of { C x1 x2 -> case (f) of { D y1 y2 -> (g) } }



  -- Any case expression with a nested constructor
  case (C u v) of { C x1 x2 -> f x1 x2 }

  -- reduces to
  f u v
  ```

  So the last subcase is the variable case:

  ```
  lem = \refutation -> case refutation (_hole :: x :~: y) of {}
  ```

  and we have to construct a `x :~: y`. We enumerate ways of filling the
  `_hole` again. It's either `Refl`, but no proof is available, or
  (skipping some steps) `case refutation (_anotherHole :: x :~: y) of {}`,
  and we have an infinite descent on our hands, which is also absurd.
  A different possible argument here is that we can pull out the `case`
  from the application, to remove this case from consideration WLOG.

  ```
  -- Any application to a case
  f (case e of C x1 x2 -> g x1 x2)

  -- is equivalent to a case with the application inside
  case e of C x1 x2 -> f (g x1 x2)
  ```

There are no more cases. The search is complete, and we didn't find an
implementation of `(x :~: y -> Void) -> Choose x y :~: 2`. QED.

To read more on this topic, I guess a course/book about lambda calculus up
until the normalization proof of the simply-typed lambda calculus should give
you the basic tools to start with. The following thesis contains an
introduction on the subject in its first part, but admittedly I'm a poor judge
of the difficulty of such material: [Which types have a unique inhabitant?
Focusing on pure program equivalence](http://gallium.inria.fr/~scherer/phd_thesis/),
by Gabriel Scherer.

Feel free to suggest more adequate resources and literature.

---

## II. Fixing the proposition and proving it with dependent types

Your initial intuition that this should encode a valid proposition
is definitely valid. How might we fix it to make it provable?

Technically, the type we are looking at is quantified with `forall`:

```
forall x y. (x :~: y -> Void) -> Choose x y :~: 2
```

An important feature of `forall` is that it is an *irrelevant* quantifier.
The variables it introduces *cannot be used "directly"* in a term of this type. Although that aspect becomes more prominent in the presence of dependent types,
it still pervades Haskell *today*, providing another intuition for why this (and many other examples) is not "provable" in Haskell: if you think about why you
think that proposition is valid, you will naturally start with a case split about whether `x` is equal to `y`, but to even do such a case split you need a way to
*decide* which side you're on, which will of course have to look at `x` and `y`,
so they cannot be irrelevant. `forall` in Haskell is not at all like what most people mean with "for all".

Some discussion on the matter of relevance can be found in the thesis [Dependent Types in Haskell](https://repository.brynmawr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1074&context=compsci_pubs), by Richard Eisenberg (in particular, Section 3.1.1.5 for an initial example, Section 4.3 for relevance in Dependent Haskell and Section 8.7 for comparison with other languages with dependent types).

Dependent Haskell will need a *relevant* quantifier to complement `forall`, and
which would get us closer to proving this:

```
foreach x y. (x :~: y -> Void) -> Choose x y :~: 2
```

Then we could probably write this:

```
lem :: foreach x y. (x :~: y -> Void) -> Choose x y :~: 2
lem x y p = case x ==? u of
  Left r -> absurd (p r)  -- x ~ y, that's absurd!
  Right Irrefl -> Refl    -- x /~ y, so Choose x y = 2
```

That also assumes a first-class notion of disequality `/~`, complementing `~`,
to help `Choose` reduce when it is in the context and a decision function
`(==?) :: foreach x y. Either (x :~: y) (x :/~: y)`.
Actually, that machinery isn't necessary, that just makes for a shorter
answer.

At this point I'm making stuff up because Dependent Haskell does not exist yet,
but that is easily doable in related dependently typed languages (Coq, Agda,
Idris, Lean), modulo an adequate replacement of the type family `Choose`
(type families are in some sense too powerful to be translated as mere
functions, so may be cheating, but I digress).

Here is a comparable program in Coq, showing also that `lem` applied to 1 and 2
and a suitable proof does reduce to a proof by reflexivity of `choose 1 2 = 2`.

https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/5a9b6996a3aae741688e7bf83903887b

---

## III. Without dependent types

A critical source of difficulty here is that `Choose` is a closed type
family with overlapping instances. It is problematic because there is
no proper way to express the fact that `x` and `y` are not equal in Haskell,
to know that the first clause `Choose x x` does not apply.

A more fruitful avenue if you're into Pseudo-Dependent Haskell is to use a
boolean type equality:

```hs
-- In the base library
import Data.Type.Bool (If)
import Data.Type.Equality (type (==))

type Choose x y = If (x == y) 1 2
```

An alternative encoding of equality constraints becomes useful for this style:

```hs
type x ~~ y = ((x == y) ~ 'True)
type x /~ y = ((x == y) ~ 'False)
```

with that, we can get another version of the type-proposition above,
expressible in current Haskell (where `SBool` is the singleton type of `Bool`),
which essentially can be read as adding the assumption that the equality of `x`
and `y` is decidable. This does not contradict the earlier claim about "irrelevance" of `forall`, the function is inspecting a boolean (or rather an `SBool`), which postpones the inspection of `x` and `y` to whoever calls `lem`.

```hs
lem :: forall x y. SBool (x == y) -> ((x ~~ y) => Void) -> Choose x y :~: 2
lem decideEq p = case decideEq of
  STrue -> absurd p
  SFalse -> Refl
```